# not all kernels show up when running jupyter no-browser

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

currently I am encountering a problem when running `jupyter notebook --no-browser --NotebookApp.allow_origin='*'`. I have configured the settings for vscode.dev according to this https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/wiki/Connecting-to-a-remote-Jupyter-server-from-vscode.dev

I can successfully connect via link http://localhost:8888, but the kernels showing up are limited and incomplete. My virtual environments are
[image]

However, only two kernels show up.
[image]

I have the latest jupyter extension [v2023.9.1102792234] and python [v2023.18.0] installed, and connecting to a Ubuntu server from a windows PC.

Greatly appreciate any comments and suggestions!!!!